# How to properly use $match in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using .aggregate and $match to filter dates and then $sample them. Right now I get an empty array. I am using the following code:

```
const result = await Event.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { event_added: condition },
      },
      { $sample: { size: 10 } },
    ]);
```

When I use .find in the code below it works perfectly, and I get all records satisfying the condition.

```
const result = await Event.find({ event_added: condition });
```

The condition object is the following:

```
var condition = { $gt: start, $lt: end };
```

Comment: A condition used with the `find` method and aggregate's `$match` stage work the same way - as you mentioned should give the same result.

Comment: Can you show the schema and also the start and end date variable

Comment: How does `start` and `end` look like? can you `console.log()` them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Model.find()` operations, mongoose can infer the data type based on your schema and converts the types in your query object accordingly.

So if `start` and `end` are not `Date` objects, mongoose will try to cast the values to `Date`, as specified in your `Event` schema.

Aggregation objects are more complex and mongoose can not automatically do type casting. If your values are not `Date` objects you'll have to convert them first before passing them to `Model.aggregate()`

Generally this should work

```
const condition = { $gt: new Date(start), $lt: new Date(end) }
```

Comment: I was using a Moment object for start and end. This solution works perfectly thank you!

Comment: If you were using moment object you can also do like this `start.toDate()`